# Are temples or shrines "buildings" or "structures"?

Tags: word-choice

When I refer to old temples or shrines in Japan, shoule I use structures or buildings? I refer to each of them as a shrine or a temple, but when I want to generalize, like all these temples, shrines, walls or whatever in certain place, which were built hundreds years ago, how should I call them?   To me, "buildings" sound like things built in this modern era. So I thought structures would be better, but sometimes I've heard people use "buildings" for that. I researched these words myself, but I'm not sure. Could you please explain the difference between two and which is the better word choice here?

Comment: Why not stick with "temples **and** shrines"? Specific is often better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A building generally is designed with walls and a roof.  There certainly can be ancient buildings.  Structures can be anything that is composed of structural components- a cell structure, a shade structure, etc. My advice is use *building* only when the referent was at least designed with walls and a roof- even if they have long since fallen in or washed away, and then only if your intent in the usage is to treat it as a whole entity whose basic nature is to have walls and a roof.  Use structure when you wish to refer to something that does not walls and a roof or when referring to a building's structural components or design rather than its essence as a closed containing structure.

> This *building* was erected in 100 BC.  - *We're talking about the whole thing as a building.*
>
> This *structure* has stood for thousands of years - *Might be a building or just a bunch of pillars, but we are talking about it's fortitude as a structure.*
>
> This building was designed to hold the King's library.  The structure's entrance is made of beams 6 feet wide. - *We can switch back and forth on what we call it based on what we're saying about it*

Comment: Then, I can call a old bridge a structure because it has no roof.  Am I right?

Comment: I think I get the clear idea of differences of these two.

Comment: @tennis girl: Some bridges [**do**](http://www.bennington.com/chamber/bridges/images/openingpagebridge.jpg) have roofs; either kind could be called a structure. In general, _bridge_ would be a better word, although you might need a more generic word every now and then, as when a journalist writes, _There were eleven structures damaged in the fire,_ which could refer to, say, six houses, one store, an office building, two bridges, and a warehouse. _Structures_ is more generic than _buildings_. If the two bridges weren't damaged, one might say, _There were nine buildings damaged in the fire._

Comment: @J.R.Thank you so much for your additional comments. It helped me understand the difference much more clearly. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. I would say that *building* is a common generic hypernym for such structures, and you could describe the places you mention as *buildings*.

However, you've correctly identified a problem with that word: it's *too* generic. The word *building* can be applied to office buildings, strip malls, houses, schools, temples, hotels, factories, stables, arenas, and restaurants. So, it's not very descriptive at all, and I don't think the word *structure* helps in that regard.

With that in mind, then, I would call the temples and shrines you mention ***places of worship***. At least that word – which has its [own entry in many dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=place%20of%20worship&ls=a) – narrows down the particular kind of building.

If you want to emphasize that these places of worship have been standing for hundreds of years, I would use the adjective *ancient*. So, here's how I would say it:

> Last week, we visited many **ancient places of worship**.

Incidentally, I checked a few places in the thesaurus, and I could find no English word that, by itself, meant "old building."  There's the word *ruins*, but that describes the physical state of a structure more than its age. Some words carry overtones of a probable long existance – such as *castle* – but castles still can be built today. I can't think of any way to emphasize that the structures have been standing for hundreds of years without using an adjective.

Comment: I just checked the link you put here. Thank you for all the research.

Comment: Not 100% matching with "old building", but "ancient monument" would be the most likely technical term in the UK - it covers everything from standing-stones to fully-habitable castles.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a temple would be a fully-grown, human-accessible building, whereas a shrine *may* be as simple as a single statue, so could while it probably is a 'construction' it could NOT be called a building.

There are various terms you could use, depending on circumstances, such as "Religious site", "Holy site" etc  but nothing comes to mind that is a single word.